# Is there a way to build solution locally in VS without having to wait for it to complete?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, automation

How do you people handle the scenario of having to build the solution multiple times every day during the development process? Our .sln takes about 2 mins to build, but waiting for those 2 minutes every day, multiple times a day during development adds to a significant number and also breaks the coding flow. Is there a better way to handle this necessity? Something that will continue to build the solution and run the test on background without the developer having to hit ctrl+shift+B and wait for the build to complete, before checking in the changes into TFS?

Comment: Why do you want to make a new build before the previous one completes? Why do you want to make multiple local builds in VS?

Comment: Have a look at NCrunch: http://www.ncrunch.net/ That could help

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler, did you set any check in policy?

Answer (score 1):

VS doesn't support building the same solution before the previous one completes. But you can achieve your requirement by using TFS Build.

When you checkin your solution into TFS, you can create a Dev branch of this solution. All changes will be checked in to Dev branch and automatically build (Gated checkin). Once the build result is what you want, then merge from Dev branch to the original solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you actually working with **Builds** **check in policy** which only allows code to be checked in after build succeed. If so, just as you described, you can't work on the project during the build. You have to wait for it to complete.